# How can one implement MV* architecture without using any framework in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are many single Page Application javascript frameworks available with MV* architecture.
But how can one implement the architecture for a very small application without using any of the framework?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too open-ended, but perhaps you could look at how for example Backbone (view models) and Underscore or Mustache (templates) are implemented to get some inspiration?

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```js
Model = {};

View = {
  update: function() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerText = Model.name;
  }
};

Controller = {
  init: function() {
    document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      Model.name = this.value;
      View.update();
    });
  }
};

window.onload = Controller.init;
```

```html
<p>Your name: <input id="in"></p>

<p>Hello, <span id="out"></span>!</p>
```